# Cant get a cell subview?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

When user choose a cell , I would like to get one of its specific UIViews and change its color.

So,

```
     func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

               for cell in collectionView.visibleCells() as [UICollectionViewCell]
            {


                     if(cell.tag==indexPath.row)
                     {
                        for view in  [cell.contentView.subviews]  {

                        view.backgroundColor=UIColor.redColor()

      //here what ever I try I can't get it to see view as a UIView and change its properties, instead I get error that [UIView] has no member..
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
{
    var selectedCell:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    selectedCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
}
```

If `tableView` is set in attribute inspector with selection to multiple Selection it should work. Just set it back in deselect:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
 {
    var cellToDeSelect:UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
    cellToDeSelect.contentView.backgroundColor = colorForCellUnselected 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way to do this. Simply get the cell you're interested in, and manipulate it directly. Using tags is a fragile method. Also, when you iterate through the subviews of another view, you're already dealing with an array, there's no need to wrap it in []s

```
  if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) {
    for view in cell.contentView.subviews {
      view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
  }
```

Comment: This is not working, it is the obvious way I have started with. On the latest Swift you get an error, because view is not recognised as a UIView.

Answer (score -1):

Your `cell.contentView.subViews` is in a array so `view` will turn out to be an array.

Loose the surrounding `[]` like this:

```
for view in cell.contentView.subviews  {
      view.backgroundColor=UIColor.redColor()
}
```